# How can I automatically deselect a mapped layer in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-cover

I am currently looking at land cover for two years, e.g. 2001 and 2010.

The code I am writing adds the Land Cover layers to the map for both years, so a map of 2001 and one of 2010. I would like my code to automatically deselect the 2010 LC layer.

```
// --- SELECT STUDY AREA ---

var studyArea = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-99.55454883653354,19.126233922295793, -98.93794117051792,19.612392241681285]);
Map.addLayer(studyArea, {}, 'studyArea');
Map.centerObject(studyArea);

var baseYear = 2001;
var studyYear = 2010;

// --- GET IMAGES ---

var landCoverStudy = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(studyYear + '-01-01',  studyYear + '-12-31'))
  .select('LC_Type1').reduce('mode').clip(studyArea);

var landCoverBase = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(baseYear + '-01-01',  baseYear + '-12-31'))
  .select('LC_Type1').reduce('mode').clip(studyArea);

var modisStyling = {
  min: 1,
  max: 17,
  palette: ['05450a','086a10','54a708','78d203','9900','c6b044',
    'dcd159','dade48','fbff13','b6ff05','27ff87','c24f44',
    'a5a5a5','ff6d4c','69fff8','f9ffa4','1c0dff']
};

Map.addLayer(landCoverBase, modisStyling, 'Land Cover (' + baseYear +')');
Map.addLayer(landCoverStudy, modisStyling, 'Land Cover (' + studyYear +')');
```

In the screenshot below I have deselected the 2010 layer, but I had to do it manually.
[image]

Instead I would like to be able to code a command that deselects the layer without manual intervention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution! First I have to assign a name to the mapped layer, e.g.:

`var mappedLayer = Map.addLayer(landCoverStudy, modisStyling, 'Land Cover - 2010');`

And when called for all I need to do is add:

`mappedLayer.setShown(0); // setShown is a boolean so 0 means hide`

Note: Naming the mapped layer doesn't always work. I recommend instead using the get function: `Map.layers().get(0).setShown(0)`

Comment: Actually, naming the mapped layer doesn't always work. I recommend instead using the get function: Map.layers().get(0).setShown(0)